# how to replace # with \# with Org export filter functions for latex

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'd like to export org file to latex, but as there are links containing # as follows, the process is interrupted.

https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-support.html#Editing-support

So I write a file for latex export as follows.

```
(defun latex-process-link-symbols (text backend info)
  "Filter links from latex export."
  (when (eq backend 'latex)
    (let ((text (replace-regexp-in-string "html#" "html\#" text)))
      )
    )
  )    
 (eval-after-load 'ox
                  '(add-to-list
                    'org-export-filter-link-functions
                    'latex-process-link-symbols))
```

But this seems not work. Can any one familiar with elisp help me to solve it?

Comment: What version of org-mode are you using? Recent versions (I run 9.1.5 on the machine where I tested) takes care of this automatically: you should not have to do anything.

Comment: Yes. Most of the # is processed properly. But I found some of them will break the export process.

Comment: Then try to find a minimal example where the problem occurs and submit it to the mailing list as a bug. And please report the org-mode version you are using: edit your question and add that information.

Comment: @Nick I am using org-mode 8.1 , I think maybe that is the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I find the replacement of # should be written in this way.

```
  (while (re-search-forward "html#" nil t)
      (replace-match "html\\\\#"))
      )
```

Comment: This is a workaround that should *NOT* be necessary. Please try to find a case where the export mechanism breaks and *submit a bug report* to the mailing list.

Comment: Also this is very limited: it will only work for "html#".